# Why doesn't Google Chrome suggest saved usernames in a drop-down menu?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, login, history, username

In firefox, when you save multiple usernames for a login site, for example gmail, firefox suggests you these saved usernames in a drop-down list when you click in the username entry box. But Google Chrome doesn't do it. Is there a way to do it?
Second question, in Firefox, when you type a few words of web-page title in address bar, it offers you the previosly visited web-pages, which is a great fefature if you want to visit a web page again. Buy Chrome doesn't offer you previously visited webpages in address bar. Is there a cure for it?

Comment: Both work for me (user names on double click), and always have (latest Chrome on a Mac). Also, please don't ask "why", but rewrite to ask for "how", and limit to one question per post, so: combine the two into one and make the title summarize that.

Comment: I dont understand how it works for you. It doesnt suggest previously visited web-pages as you type in address bar. Instead, it suggests google search results.

Comment: Please investigate a bit more and update your question: what do you see, what do you expect? For me it surely includes results that Google does not know about (like URLs to non-public development servers, or simple localhost URLs). (I assume you're not running some incognito mode?)

Comment: sir, when I type "book" in addressbar in firefox, it suggest me previously visited pages which contains word "book" in its title bar, as well as url. But chrome doesn't suggest it. For example, say the previously visited page has title "The books about civil engineering", when I type "book" in address bar, it will be suggested by firefox. chrome doesn't do it.

Comment: No, *your* Chrome doesn't. [Mine does](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JltRi.png). So, I'm afraid people need much more detail to be able to help you.